# Create a wallet pass with jpasskit using ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

I need to create and manage apple wallet passes.  I'm trying to use jpasskit with ColdFusion.  I also want to create the pass dynamically (the information on each pass changes on the pass.json file).

Right now, I'm trying to create a main java class to run the code according to the jpasskit tutorial in step 2:

Assuming that I have provided the correct info for:
appleWWDRCA
privateKeyPath
privateKeyPassword

"Step 2
Checkout Jpasskit from github with this command "git clone https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit" or fork it on github. Either way will work. Start by making a simple java class with a main method and paste this code into the method."

```
import java.util.*;
import IPKValidateable.java;
import PKBarcode.java;
import PKBeacon.java;
import PKField.java;
import PKLocation.java;
import PKNFC.java;
import PKPass.java;
import PKPushToken.java;
import PWAssociatedApp.java;


        public class mypass 
    { 
        ppublic static void main(String[])
        { 
    String appleWWDRCA = "passbook/AppleWWDRCA.pem"; // this is apple's developer relation cert
            String privateKeyPath = "./privateKey.p12"; // the private key you exported from keychain
            String privateKeyPassword = "password"; // the password you used to export
            try {

                PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = PKSigningUtil.
                        loadSigningInformationFromPKCS12FileAndIntermediateCertificateFile(
                        privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassword, appleWWDRCA);

                PKPass pass = new PKPass();
                pass.setPassTypeIdentifier("pass.com.yourdomain.type");
                pass.setAuthenticationToken("vxwxd7J8AlNNFPS8k0a0FfUFtq0ewzFdc");
                pass.setSerialNumber("12345678000");
                pass.setTeamIdentifier("abcdefg"); // replace this with your team ID
                pass.setOrganizationName("your org");
                pass.setDescription("some description");
                pass.setLogoText("some logo text");

                PKBarcode barcode = new PKBarcode();
                barcode.setFormat(PKBarcodeFormat.PKBarcodeFormatPDF417);
                barcode.setMessageEncoding(Charset.forName("iso-8859-1"));
                barcode.setMessage("123456789");
                pass.setBarcode(barcode);

                PKGenericPass generic = new PKGenericPass();
                List<PKField> primaryFields = new ArrayList<PKField>();
                PKField member = new PKField();
                member.setKey("mykey"); // some unique key for primary field
                member.setValue("myvalue"); // some value
                primaryFields.add(member);
                generic.setPrimaryFields(primaryFields);
                pass.setGeneric(generic);

                PKLocation location = new PKLocation();
                location.setLatitude(37.33182); // replace with some lat
                location.setLongitude(-122.03118); // replace with some long
                List<PKLocation> locations = new ArrayList<PKLocation>();
                locations.add(location);
                pass.setLocations(locations);

                if (pass.isValid()) {
                    String pathToTemplateDirectory = "./mypass.raw"; // replace with your folder with the icons
                    byte[] passZipAsByteArray = PKSigningUtil.
                            createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, pathToTemplateDirectory, pkSigningInformation);

                    String outputFile = "./mypass.pkpass"; // change the name of the pass
                    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(passZipAsByteArray);
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
                    System.out.println("Done!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("the pass is NOT Valid man!!!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("failed!");
            }
    }
    }
```

**I got these errors:**

0: error: cannot find symbol
            PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = PKSigningUtil.
            ^
  symbol:   class PKSigningInformation
  location: class main

cannot find symbol
            PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = PKSigningUtil.
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable PKSigningUtil
  location: class main

I'm not sure if I created the main file correct.  Can anyone with Java background help?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you import those classes? Do you have any `import` statements in your code?

Comment: The tutorial does not have any import statement in there.  So I'm not sure if it needed to import additional library.  Should I include an import?

Comment: That depends on whether you want your code to work or not. Only classes in the `java.lang` package are imported automatically. The compiler won't have any idea what you're talking about if you write `PKPass` and haven't imported the class (or the package).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.  I now need to import all the classes that needs to run this code properly.

Comment: @Mrfroddo - What does this have to do with ColdFusion? :-) Sounds like a purely "java" question.

Comment: @Ageax Eventually I will need to integrate this with ColdFusion to create the wallet pass.

Comment: @Kayaman After importing all the files, it still does not work.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: That's not the way to import classes. You also need to learn how to include the classes in the classpath (and understand what the classpath is). But it gets a bit too broad. I recommend you read some basic Java tutorials to get some samples compiling, then get back to this.

Comment: @Mrfroddo - But that'll be a separate thread ;-) Anyway, regarding the error your import statements are incorrect. A) You need to include the path to the class, like `path.to.PKPushToken` and don't include an extension. Drop the `.java`. But like @Kayaman mentioned, there are other elements to it and "how to compile" is a bit broad a topic for S.O.

Comment: @Mrfroddo - I'd assume the project already provides a compiled jar. If not, see Maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.brendamour/jpasskit/0.0.9.  Unless you're doing this for educational purposes, instead of trying to write a java class, why not just use the jar in ColdFusion, then write the equivalent CF code?

Comment: @Ageax Yes, that'll be a separate thread ;) This is a learning experience for me but I do want to make it work.  I've never used jar with cf before.  If you can point me to the right direction I would appreciated!

Comment: @Ageax I found something that someone wrote similar to what you suggested. But I'm not sure how to implemented.
https://github.com/dawesi/cfwheels-passkit

Comment: I've never used it but it looks like a component wrapper of the java library with most of the same methods. I'd assume you 1) download all the files 2) [load the jars](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html) in your Application.cfc and 3) create an instance of the CFC then call the appropriate methods. If you run into problems, open a new thread with your code and any error messages.

Comment: "This is a learning experience for me" Those are always good :) The exact "how" of it depends on which IDE you're using. IIRC, importing into Eclipse as a Maven project is the easiest. It *should* set up the classpath for you, so in theory all you need to do is create your test class with the correct `import` statements and `main(String[] args)` method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: BTW, if you're new, might want to take the [Tour].  S.O. is very different than traditional forums. It's more focused on "ask a question, post an answer", maybe add a few comments if you have questions, but long comment threads are discouraged and are often deleted. So don't be surprised if this whole thread disappears ;-)

Comment: @Ageax Thanks! I'm a newbie here.  I'll take your advise and create a new thread.

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: Mumzee, I wasn't able to make it to work at that time but I haven't gone back to try it.